# How to delete a file once it is created by an app?

Tags: applications, internal-storage, file-management, media-scanner

This question applies to any file created by an app, but this is the description of my problem.

I have an app installed in my phone that creates a .nomedia file in the root of my storage every time a specific action happens in the app. This causes all media files on my phone not to appear in gallery applications because the media scanner ignores everything.

I have contacted the app but they still did not have managed to solve that problem. What I want to know then is if there is a way to immediately delete the .nomedia file as soon as it is created by the app.

Comment: Remove that app, simply

Comment: That does not provide an answer to my question.

Comment: that's probably why I choosed to comment instead ;)

Comment: I need to use the app, so deleting it is not possible.

Comment: This should be a bug or something with your app. an App shouldn't create a .nomedia file inside system media folders. May be it is not configured properly to use its own folder

Comment: Yes, this certainly is a bug. But while they not fix it I am trying to avoid having to delete the file manually every time it is created.

Comment: Apps like Tasker can watch a certain directory for changes and execute a command if a change occurs.

Comment: @Robert I ended up using Tasker as you mentioned. If possible, please create an answer so that I can accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Monitoring a directory for a newly created or modified file is a simple task for an app as Android provides an API for doing so.

Therefore a lot of apps include file monitoring capabilities, such as [Automate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate) or [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm). In these apps you can monitor the file as add a trigger to delete the file that will be executed immediately when the file is created.